# One android application, two startup view, two two icons

Tags: android

I have my simple notepad application.
It display input text and save button when launching. Everything works fine.

Now I want to keep all app logic, but use "second icon" to launch my app with other initial view (I want to set up numbers only filter on input text).

In other words:

- first icon runs general notepad app, user can input everything he wants
- second icon runs notpad that accepts only numbers.

Is there any method to create second icon/widget w/e to inform app that it should run in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another activity to your application,

also add that activyty to AndroidManidest with

different Icon and with intent-filter
as action=main and catagory=LAUNCHER

Just see:

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:icon="@drawable/ICON1"
                                    ^^^^^^
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
                           ^^^^^^
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:icon="@drawable/ICON222"
                                    ^^^^^^^^
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
                           ^^^^^^
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Also add another XML for only Number Type Input If needed.